# How to rewrite old backup copies windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup

How to configure backup on windows server 2008, for rewriting old backup copies automatically? Now I have 24 copies and windows doesn't create new because no free space on HD. But I need to delete old copies automatically.

[image]